# playframework scala futures and asynchronism fetching data and manipulating object

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm having a brainlack and don't know what to do in this case:

```
process.flatMap({ case (..., processSteps, ...) =>
      Future.sequence {
        processSteps.map { step =>
            val prerequisiteFuture = processStepPrerequisitesDTO.getProcessStepPrerequisiteProcessTemplateIds(step.id.get)

            prerequisiteFuture.map(prereqTemplates => {
              Future.successful{
                processTemplateDTO.getProessTemplatesForStepPreqrequsites(prereqTemplates).map(pres => {
                  println("Returning something", pres) // they are printed
                  step.stepPrerequisites = Some(pres)
                })
              }
              println("Obviously empty", step.stepPrerequisites)
              step // line x
            })
        }
      }.map { stepTemplates =>
          Ok(Json.obj(
            ...
            "steps" -> stepTemplates,
            ...
          ))
      }
    })
```

How can I achive that `step.prerequisites` in line x is no longer empty? Thanks!

Comment: Concurrency and mutability doesn't play very well. Better rewrite this

Comment: Can you give me an advice or better an example how to rewrite it?

Comment: what's the use of `Future.successful` ? does `processTemplateDTO.getProessTemplatesForStepPreqrequsites` also return a `Future`? As said above, get rid of the mutability, replace `step.stepPrerequisites = Some(pres)` by simply `pres` and work it up from there...

Comment: can you please give a full example? Don't understand what you mean. 
it has to be Some(pres) because its an option in model.

Future.successfull isn't necessary in this case